How handle Dialogflow CX Critical Errors in the middle of the conversation?
I am using Dialogflow CX console do develop a bot, I have the webhook error event to handle any problem about calling my webhook like a timeout for example
enter image description here
But for example, if I route page A for page B or flow A for flow B and in the middle of the way of this route I have a timeout, quota issue or any other generic error due a Google or Dialogflow instability how can I handle it?
I saw Google has a built-in event called flow.fail
enter image description here
but it seems to work in a different way of webhook error for example in webhook error I can trigger it forcing a timeout and it will display a message and send me for where I want using routes, but how can I trigger flow.fail? It seems that it is only triggered by END_FLOW_WITH_FAILURE page, but how can I send the user for that page if I have a problem in any part of my Dialogflow agent.
Goal: - Handle Critical Errors in the middle of the conversation between Dialogflow and User
Thanks for help :)
